# Why is it true that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Why is it true that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$?

My procedure:

Let $h=x-a$, then $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(a)-f(-x)}{x-a}$. If we can manage to make $f(a)-f(-x)=f(x)-f(a)$, then it's done, but how do we do that?

Comment: You are just making the wrong substitution. Put x=a-h instead.

Comment: @CoolKid You also went wrong while substituting. What I mean is $ f(a-h) = f(a-(x-a)) = f(2a-x) $and not $f(-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting $x-a=h$ try letting

> $$ a-x=h$$

In order to reach to the given simplification instantly.

Comment: But how does $a\to x$ make sense?

Comment: @CoolKid I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate what do you wanna ask?

Comment: @CoolKid: why do you think the substitution $a-x=h$ seems to imply $a\to x$. Note that $x\to a$ is a given and you can't change that. And the substitution $h=a-x$ introduces a new variable $h$ in place of $x$ and things change accordingly so that $x$ becomes $a-h$ and $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a hint**

Put $a-x=h $
thus
$$\frac {f (x)-f (a)}{x-a}=\frac {f (a-h)-f (a)}{-h} $$

and
$$|h|<\eta \iff |x-a|<\eta $$

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that to find derivative of a function at a point, we just have to find the instantaneous rate of change of function with respect to $x$. Essentially when you are calculating both the limits , you are making, both change in x and change in function approach zero and calculating the ratio which need not be necessarily zero. Just reconsider both the limits and see what they mean intuitively and you will come to know how both of them are equal and essentially the derivative of the function at that point.

Also, you don't have to actually make $$f(x)-f(a)=f(a)-f(2a-x)$$ [*See my comment*]

but you have to only show that when $x$ approaches $a$ both are equal, and that is true, as you will see.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $h=x-a$, then $a-h=a-(x-a)=2a-x$, so the limit you get is
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(a)-f(2a-x)}{x-a}
$$
which is no easier than the one you started from.

An easier way is to do $h=-k$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(a)-f(a+k)}{-k}=
\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(a+k)-f(a)}{k}=f'(a)
$$